# Validating JWT token ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application.

In the application I have an AuthController like:

```
   [HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
    {
        var userToCreate = new IdentityUser(userForRegisterDto.Username);
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userForRegisterDto.Password);

        return Ok(new
        {
            token = GenerateJwtToken(userToCreate).Result,
            user = result
        });

    }

    private async Task<string> GenerateJwtToken(IdentityUser user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName)
        };

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
          .GetBytes(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = creds
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

As you can see, when registering, the API sends a JWT token back to the client.
I would like to validate this token against all controllers in the application.

I know I have to add some logic in the `Startup.cs` file but I just can't figure out what. Can anyone help me achieving this?

Comment: what do you mean by validate? You want to insert an identity from that token to http context?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a global auth filter:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                             .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
```

Or add `[Authorize]` above the controller.